# Laravel sending a reset password link in a notification

Tags: laravel, notifications, change-password

I am using a notification to send an email to a user that someone created an account for them.  What I am trying to figure out is how to send them an action to the password/reset page.  I need to add a token to reset the password to the end of the password/reset address.  If not when the user tries to reset the password they get a invalid token error.  So what do I need to add to the end of url so there is a valid token?

```
$passwordReset = 'localhost/password/reset'
```

How do I add a valid token to reset the password to the end of the code above code?

Comment: `'localhost/password/reset?token='.$token`

Comment: Where is the token stored?  Is it in the users table, then you just need to append the $user->token to your link.  It seems to me that you don't know what the password reset contoller method verifies the token against.  You need to know that, so you know what token to send along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the url should be

```
localhost/password/reset/{token}
```

eg:

```
localhost/password/reset/15966e3b4460a10a025d2506609e2857d89eea6eed77e898e41922873111afa4
```

For it to work properly all four password routes must be active (if using default laravel auth):

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna send mail with the token you can make that
and you can use

```
Route::post('/PasswordReset', 'ResetPasswordController@GetToken');
```

then send Token by mail 
where you can save token you may not even save it 
you can use the Username there is function called bcrypt();
you can hashing his username by it 
and it will give you long token but i dont prefer that bec the token wont change

i prefer send him new password to mail and make him login then change password 
you can use str_random(8);
it will generate 8 random number with letters

Trying Help You 
First you must config your mail go to Config/mail.php
and add this after driver

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Second Go to you .env file change this to your host details list try with gmail one

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=yourgmailMail@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Third go to your Controller that you will make send mail function in lists Assume its name is SendMassEmailController
[This is the Whole Controller](https://codepad.co/snippet/zz6A9k3p)

last thing is the route
go to web.php

```
Route::post('/SendMassEmail','SendMassEmailController@SendMassEmail');
```

Finally Good Luck and Have Fun